# como criar top em php a partir de informações de banco de dados

Tags: php

Fiz uma página administrativa onde eu cadastro em um formulário as informações de livros e sua posição (1º, 2º lugar...), mas não consigo resgatar do banco de dados as informações que preciso. Minha necessidade é que, a partir da sua posição, eu coloque os dados em html:

```
<article id="top">
      <?php       
        include "acessoResponsivo.php";
           $comando="select * from tb_top";
           $matriz=mysql_query($comando);
           $linha=mysql_fetch_array($matriz);
           $posicao=$linha["posicao"];


            if ($posicao=="1") {
        ?> 
            <h2>Top mais lidos</h2>
            <div id="topum" class="numeracao">
            <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
            <h4 class="num">1</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>    

        <?php    
            }

        //__________________________________dois_____________

            else if ($posicao=="2") {
        ?>
            <div id="topdois" class="numeracao">
            <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
            <h4 class="num">2</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>        
        <?php    
            }
        //__________________________________tres_____________

            else if ($posicao=="3") {
        ?>
            <div id="toptres" class="numeracao">
            <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
            <h4 class="num">3</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>
        <?php    
            }
        //__________________________________quatro_____________

            else if ($posicao=="4") {
        ?>              
            <div id="topquatro" class="numeracao">
            <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
            <h4 class="num">4</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>
        <?php    
            }
        //__________________________________cinco_____________

            else if ($posicao=="5") {
        ?>          
            <div id="topcinco" class="numeracao">
            <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
            <h4 class="num">5</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>
        <?php    
            }
        ?>          

    </article>
```

Comment: Qual a estrutura da sua tabela tb_top? Edita sua pergunta com a estrutura.

Comment: Bem-vinda Caroline, não deixe de ler esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Assim vai funcionar

```
<article id="top">
  <?php       
    include "acessoResponsivo.php";

       $comando="select * from tb_top";
       $matriz=mysql_query($comando); 

    while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($matriz)){

        $posicao=$linha["posicao"];

        if ($posicao=="1") {
    ?> 
        <h2>Top mais lidos</h2>
        <div id="topum" class="numeracao">
        <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
        <h4 class="num">1</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>    

    <?php    
        }

    //__________________________________dois_____________

        else if ($posicao=="2") {
    ?>
        <div id="topdois" class="numeracao">
        <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
        <h4 class="num">2</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>        
    <?php    
        }
    //__________________________________tres_____________

        else if ($posicao=="3") {
    ?>
        <div id="toptres" class="numeracao">
        <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
        <h4 class="num">3</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>
    <?php    
        }
    //__________________________________quatro_____________

        else if ($posicao=="4") {
    ?>              
        <div id="topquatro" class="numeracao">
        <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
        <h4 class="num">4</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>
    <?php    
        }
    //__________________________________cinco_____________

        else if ($posicao=="5") {
    ?>          
        <div id="topcinco" class="numeracao">
        <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
        <h4 class="num">5</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>
    <?php    
        }

        } //end while
    ?>          

</article>
```

> **Visto que o MySQL foi descontinuado, sugiro migrar para MySQLi ou PDO**

<sup>Se você está preocupado com performance e não tem interesse em portabilidade, a melhor opção é sempre o mysqli.</sup>

**Com MySQLi**

```
<article id="top">
<?php
include "acessoResponsivo.php";

  $consulta = "SELECT * FROM tb_top";
  $result = $conn->query($consulta);

  while($linha = $result->fetch_array()){

    $posicao=$linha["posicao"];

    if ($posicao=="1") {
    ?> 
        <h2>Top mais lidos</h2>
        <div id="topum" class="numeracao">
        <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
        <h4 class="num">1</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>    

    <?php    
        }

    //__________________________________dois_____________

        else if ($posicao=="2") {
    ?>
        <div id="topdois" class="numeracao">
        <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
        <h4 class="num">2</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>        
    <?php    
        }
    //__________________________________tres_____________

        else if ($posicao=="3") {
    ?>
        <div id="toptres" class="numeracao">
        <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
        <h4 class="num">3</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>
    <?php    
        }
    //__________________________________quatro_____________

        else if ($posicao=="4") {
    ?>              
        <div id="topquatro" class="numeracao">
        <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
        <h4 class="num">4</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>
    <?php    
        }
    //__________________________________cinco_____________

        else if ($posicao=="5") {
    ?>          
        <div id="topcinco" class="numeracao">
        <?php echo '<img src="img/' .$linha["imagemtop"]. '.jpg"> <br/> '; ?>
        <h4 class="num">5</h4> <br> <?php echo '<p class="toptitulo">'.$linha["toptitulo"].'</p> '; ?></div>
    <?php    
        }

  } //end while
?>          

</article>
```

**acessoResponsivo.php**

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","USUARIO","SENHA", "NOME_DB");
```